# Runtime error while using bottomnavigation

Tags: java, android, navigation, runtime, android-navigation

I'm new in android studio. I need to make bottom navigation and different fragemnet working with it. when I run the app the, 'app stop responding' message appears. I cannot find the issue.
and i have a runtime error saying this:

```
   

      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: np.com.app.journeyjournal, PID: 28863
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
        ComponentInfo{np.com.app.journeyjournal/np.com.app.journeyjournal.MainActivity}: 
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity np.com.app.journeyjournal.MainActivity@33614f5 does 
        not have a NavController set on 2131230919
```

mainactivity.java file is:

```
    package np.com.app.journeyjournal;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.navigation.NavController;
    import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
    import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
    
    import android.os.Bundle;
    
    import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
            NavController navController;
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
            navController = Navigation.findNavController(this,  R.id.fragment);
    
            NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,navController);
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a NavHostFragment in your xml file?

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

Comment: I also add NavHostFragement in my xml file: `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
 
  
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nev" />`